# reset input fields not working (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, input

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucheron/XVq3n/15/

When I start a list of items and I click on "Clear", I would like to text input be cleared as well.I'm not able to clear the fields

```
<input type="text" placeholder ="Add List" id="listItem"/>
<button id="addButton">add Item</button>
<button id="clearButton">Clear Items</button>
<ul id="output"></ul>

clearButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var text = document.getElementById('listItem').value;
    var addItem = document.getElementById('output');
    addItem.innerHTML = '';
    text.value = '';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just need to make this change here:

```
var text = document.getElementById('listItem');
```

You had this:

```
var text = document.getElementById('listItem').value;
```

What you are doing is getting the value of the input text, when you actually want the input element.

Also here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XVq3n/16/

Answer (score 2):

you are referring in your code to input's value, replace

```
var text = document.getElementById('listItem').value
```

with

```
var text = document.getElementById('listItem')
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it's a really simple (but easy to make) error. Try this change and it should work:

```
clearButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var text = document.getElementById('listItem');
    var addItem = document.getElementById('output');
    addItem.innerHTML = '';
    text.value = '';
});
```

Basically, you did .value one too many times. Hope that helps.